# What is the equivalent of HttpContext.GetOwinContext() from a Hub?

Tags: c#, .net, http, authentication, signalr

I made a OWIN SignalR server self-hosted in a console app.

From an example that is hosting SignalR in a ASP.NET MVC application instead (in IIS), I see this line of code:

```
var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
```

I do not have access to `HttpContext` in my console app (and do not want to reference the System.Web.Mvc assembly if possible). What would be the equivalent of `HttpContext.GetOwinContext()` in my SignalR hub class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OwinRequestScopeContext/

In Configuration:

`app.UseRequestScopeContext();`

In hub:

```
new Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext(OwinRequestScopeContext.Current.Environment)
```